# 4.3.1 to 4.4 - WYSIWYG Editor Issues

Tags: upgrade, wysiwyg

I've just upgraded my WordPress site from 4.3.1 to 4.4, and I've just come across an issue which I've tested, and it does seem to happen upon upgrading the core from 4.3.1 to 4.4.

When I go into a post or page with a WYSIWYG editor, I cannot switch tabs between 'Visual' and 'Text'. Whatever the tab was before the upgrade, it's stuck on.

Anyone else had this issue?

(I think quite  a few styles and scripts are loaded through the header.php so I'm going to move these to the functions.php file, registering them and enqueing them so I can load them only when not in the admin area.)

Here's the only JavaScript error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'toolbar1' of undefined`

Comment: Are you using Advanced Custom Fields Plugin?  WYSIWYG included with _WordPress_ should work perfectly. If I recall correctly, this bug happened with ACF few months back, have you updated it?

Comment: I do have ACF, I just disabled it and the issue still occurs.

Comment: Do you get any JS error on console?

Comment: That's the first thing I checked, and I saw nothing. However, now I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'toolbar1' of undefined`.

Comment: As always with errors: disable every single plugin and check if the problem  still exists. If that's not helping, switch your theme to check again. Im not getting any errors.

Comment: Disabling Advanced Custom Fields gets rid of the error I posted above. But the issue still persists.

Comment: This site has 22 plugins (sigh), I've just disabled them all and the issue is fixed. I guess one of these plugins is very outdated. I'll get back to you on which is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A plugin was the cause of this issue, '**PS Disable Auto Formatting**'. After disabling this plugin, the issue was fixed.